# Image to image translation from image to sketch using GANs, do I need to annotated the face at all?

Tags: data-cleaning, preprocessing, gan, generative-models

So far I have read 2 papers on GANs and it seems like they are unsupervised networks that only uses supervision for the discriminator. If I want to translate an image from a picture to line art all I need to do is to prepare my ground truth "the unmodified picture" and the corresponding line art correct? Do I have to pre-classify any facial feature for the generator to learn the corresponding line art or is that what Conditional GANs are for? I am trying to brainstorm my own project but the data preprocessing stage is a little hazy.

Comment: Can I suggest a completely different method to convert an mage to line art?

Comment: Sure please I want to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring an original image to a different style of image is called **style transfer**. Although you can use a GAN for such a case, I am not convinced this is the best approach. Furthermore, there have been many papers recently published suggesting very interesting ways for which to train models for style transfer. An amazing implementation of a file transfer algorithm which can convert video in real time can be found [here](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer).

There is another method that I have come across more recently which uses the same approach but a different loss function. The paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08155.pdf).

## The underlining method

These methods use a combination of two networks. The first network acts as a transformation function $f_W$ which maps your image $x$ to a transformed image $\hat{y}$. The purpose is to train this network such that the output $\hat{y}$ is the original input image in the new style, in your case as line art. To train this network we will use the second network on the right side which learns how to mix in the *Style Target* and the *Content Target*. We want the transformed image $\hat{y}$ is still similar in content, but we want the transformed image to have a similar style as the target.

To train this network we will use a massive amount of input images using some online database source. This training process will be very long. However, once it is complete then we can strip the network on the right side and you will only need the network which approximates $f_W$. You will then be able to put a new image into the input of this network and the output will be the line art version of the input image.

You will need to tune the extent at which the input image is *line artified* by tuning the weight on the style loss during the training.

[image]

Comment: Hi I am going to vote your answer as the correct answer, thanks for the reply! I have actually decided to pivot my personal project in a different approach which requires me to learn and generate new unseen data from a distribution. This works really with a GAN model so thanks for help!

Comment: Yeah that would be the correct use for a GAN. A GAN learns to generate data from a given distributions.